# Type 'number' is not assignable to type className []

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am getting error

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type DeviceInput []

This is my code

```
id:number
reprobj:Reprocess;
this.reprobj.DeviceIds=this.id;
```

Model class code

```
export class DeviceInput
{
    ID:number
}

export class Reprocess
{
    Flag:boolean
    ProductID:number
    DeviceIds: DeviceInput[]
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Either by changing the type of DeviceIds to number if that's what it should be (unlikely), or by initiaizing DeviceIds with an array of DeviceInput instead of initializing it with a number.

Comment: I want to used 2nd option. How can I do it

Comment: So create an array of DevideInput. And initialize the DeviceIds property with that array. What's the concrete issue?

Comment: I am very new to Angular,don't know how to do that

Comment: That has nothing to do with Angular. It has to do with JavaScript/TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

This is an array:

```
DeviceIds: DeviceInput[]
```

This is a number:

```
id:number
```

You can't assign a number to an array. So make some changes:

```
export class DeviceInput
{
    ID: number;

    constructor(_id:number) {
        this.ID = _id;
    }
}

export class Reprocess
{
    Flag: boolean;
    ProductID: number;
    DeviceIds: DeviceInput[] = [];
}
```

Your code:

```
this.reprobj.DeviceIds.push(new DeviceInput(someId));
```

Comment: What to write at `new DeviceInput()`

Comment: Instantitate the DeviceInput object with your id e.g: `new DeviceInput(1337)`

Comment: How to get `DeviceInput` class in Compnent.ts file to pass in `push`

Comment: Inside one file Reprocess.ts I have two classes `DeviceInput` and `Reprocess`

Comment: if you need both classes: `import {DeviceInput, Reprocess} from './Reprocess';`

Comment: Sometimes I have to pass multiple values so having single value in constructor wll no work

Comment: Then create the object before you push it. `let di = new DeviceItem(1); di.someValue = 2; `

Comment: getting error at `this.reprobj.DeviceIds.push(new DeviceInput(someId));` like undefigned push

Comment: Do you have initialized reprobj?  `reprobj:Reprocess = new Reprocess();`

Comment: Yeah, but looks `reprobj.DeviceIds` not working bcz `reprobj.ProductId` I am able to assign value.